# bootstrap TimePicker Plugin : set full time hour/minutes/seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I work With [bootstrap Timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) Plugin and Need to set full time (`H:i:s`).

on initialization timepicker Work Only With this Format `11:42 PM/AM`:

```
$('someSelector').timepicker('setTime': '11:42 PM');
```

But My Time Is : `12:12:12` And This Not work With timepicker.

How do fix this ?!

**I Found :**

Using : `defaultValue: '12:45:30'` and `showSeconds: true` This Worked Perfectly.

```
 $('#timepicker2').timepicker({disableFocus: true,showInputs: false,showSeconds: true,showMeridian: false,defaultValue: '12:45:30'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found :

Using : `defaultValue: '12:45:30'` and `showSeconds: true` This Worked Perfectly.

```
 $('#timepicker2').timepicker(
    {
     disableFocus: true,
     showInputs: false,
     showSeconds: true,
     showMeridian: false,
     defaultValue: '12:45:30'
     }
 );
```

Comment: The version I have works with `defaultTime` instead of `defaultValue`

Comment: I just want display only Minutes and Seconds. can give a Solution.